# Avoid bringing down ethernet iface when cable is unplugged

Tags: networking, network-interface, ethernet

I have a device connected to my computer via Ethernet cable (I am actually using a USB to Ethernet adapter), and sometimes I have tu turn this device on and off .

The `interfaces` file for the Ethernet interface (the adapter) is the following

```
auto enx000ec6a358e6
allow-hotplug enx000ec6a358e6
iface enx000ec6a358e6 inet static
address 192.168.1.175
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
gateway 192.168.1.175
```

The connection works fine, but when I turn off and on the external device, the system detects that the link is gone down and every time I need to manually bring up Ethernet interface every time

`# ifconfig enx000ec6a358e6`

even if the content of `/sys/class/net/enx000ec6a358e6/operstate` is 'up`.
Seems that the interface goes into a relinquish state..

Is there a simple configuration to avoid this behavior (avoid bringing down the interface on link disconnection) rather than checking some sys file (which one in this case ?) using a bash loop ?

Comment: Wouldn't udevd rules help?

Comment: Can udev rules detect a cable (not the USB adapter) disconnection ?